# How to get Login Activity only once when i runned for first time and next time differnt activities should come

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i run application,Login Activity should come only once  for first time and next time ,when i open two different Activities should come based on button click in Login Activity.
In login activity i kept two radio  buttons if i enable first radio button next time when i opened it should show main2 layout and if i enabled second radio button it should show main3 layout.

```
     public class Demo1 extends Activity {
        Button b1,b2;
        int count=0;
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
      boolean firstrun=settings.getBoolean("firstrun",true);
      if (firstrun) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();
        e.putBoolean("firstrun",false);
        e.commit();


      setContentView(R.layout.main1);
      }
      else{
         test();
      }
      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
     b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            count=1;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Demo1.this, ButtonActivate1.class);
              startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
     b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count=2;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Demo1.this, ButtonActivate1.class);
              startActivity(intent);
        }
    });




 }
private void test() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(count==1)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    }
    if(count==2)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);
    }
}
```

}

In this example when i am running it is getting force closed and showing error in the line button.setonclicklistner.please suggest me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated my answer to the following. This should work for you now.

```
package com.demo1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Demo1Activity extends Activity {
    private int count;
    private SharedPreferences settings;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        settings = this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
        count = settings.getInt("count", 0);

        selectContentView();
    }

    public void button1Method(View v) {
        setCount(1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Demo1Activity.this, Demo2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void button2Method(View v) {
        setCount(2);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Demo1Activity.this, Demo3Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    private void selectContentView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (count) {
        case 1:
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);
            break;
        case 2:
            setContentView(R.layout.main3);
            break;
        default:
            setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        }
    }

    private void setCount(int count) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();
        e.putInt("count",count);
        e.commit();
    }
}
```

The main1.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="main1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:onClick="button1Method"
            android:text="button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:onClick="button2Method"
            android:text="button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have replaced the onClick listeners to be set within the XML file. I find this neater and easier.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Demo1Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Demo2Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Demo3Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: means i should do in button on click then for the first time it is showing error first time also it is not runnin

Comment: There are lots of problems in your code. (i) you are defining `int count = 0;` when the class initializes...therefore you are always going to get count = 0 when the application restarts. So test will never work. Let me look more into it

Comment: The example above works. Tested it! Don't forget to make sure you have your second and third activities declared within your manifest file, this will throw an exception if you call an intent to open an activity and you have not declared them in the manifest file.

Comment: thanks for your response.i tried the code which you sent but here when i close the application and when i open again it is going to default  setContentView(R.layout.main1);

Comment: How are you closing it? It is working fine for me. Because I had not put any way for it to reset back to 0, i have to uninstall/clear data to have it show main1.xml again. I have tried killing it and it still brings whatever i have selected

Comment: yes if i click button 2 and click escape button then when i open apps again then it is showing default page

Comment: ahh i know what you are doing now. You are pressing button 2 then pressing the android back button, this returns you to the initial activity. you are then closing the application (it is calling onPause) and then openeing it again (this is calling onResume) and it is still showing the last activity you were on. if you were to open task manager and kill the application, you would see that it would actually open whatever button you had selected. but what you are doing is not killing the application you are just pausing it. because we have not put a method in onResume to check, it will go

Comment: Therefore we can add something in onResume to check aswell, i will edit the above code

Comment: I have been looking at what to put in onResume and I am thinking dont worry about it. If the application closes (i.e. is killed) it will start at whatever option has been set. I think if they press back and pause the app, its not big deal. if the application is shut and restarted it will work fine.

Comment: here in default view main i took two text views i need to set date and time for them     textdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
    texttime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
    final Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => "+ca.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
    SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    formattedDate = df.format(ca.getTime());
    formattedDate1=df1.format(ca.getTime());
   textdate.setText(formattedDate);
    texttime.setText(formattedDate1);

Comment: but if i run first time it is not showing any error but if i open next time it showing error at textdate.setText(formattedDate);