# User Settings - Android

Tags: android, settings

How to make in app changes persist so that when app relaunches all settings remain same(like if from app i have selected vibration then when app is not running if my phone is ringer mode when app relaunches it sets itself to vibration)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's actually multiple ways to persist changes. The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) covers all of them in more detail, but essentially these are the five ways. Easiest is `SharedPreferences`, probably.

`Shared Preferences`

Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

`Internal Storage`

Store private data on the device memory.

`External Storage`

Store public data on the shared external storage.

`SQLite Databases`

Store structured data in a private database.

`Network Connection`

Store data on the web with your own network server.

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences. You can put key value pairs and retrieve when needed .

Answer (score 1):

You need to store these settings within the Database. On how to use this see [Using Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Comment: How do i store a toggle check event like when i check the button turns vibration on return to app vibrtion should be active

Comment: Refer to Waynn Lue's comments about different ways, but you could either store it as a boolean or as an int (ie. 0 is off, 1 is on). The shared preferences option might be the easiest solution. Checkout this answer for how to work with shared preferences - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10346735/1355591)

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences

Save your settings:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 
editor.putString("email", "my_email@email.com"); 
editor.putString("name", "Albert"); 
editor.commit();
```

Retrieve them:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);   
String email = prefs.getString("email", "default@email.com");
```

Comment: I have a toggle button, if checked  turns device on vibration mode. Now out of app i turn t ringer mode when i return where i call get string is giving Nullpointer Exception

Answer (score 1):

Thing that you could do is to create a PreferenceActivity like :

```
public class Prefs  extends PreferenceActivity  {   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
    }

}
```

In res/xml folder add preference.xml with this content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="General" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="notification"
            android:summaryOff="You will not receive any notification"
            android:summaryOn="Notifications are sent to your device"
            android:title="Get notification" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

In your code you can do now :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Boolean sendNotification = prefs.getBoolean("notification", false);
```